# Can't override list.phtml in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, frontend, magento2.4

I try to override the list.phtml in Magento 2.4 but it's not working.
Here is the path to my new file :

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/timeote/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

All the other phtml that I edit in the same path are working, such as this one :

```
app/design/frontend/Magento/timeote/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml
```

Am I missing something with list.phtml ?
Thank you for your answers because I'm stuck with this ...

Comment: Perhaps list.phtml is already being extended by a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

1. Override file in your theme

app/design/frontend/vendor_namespace/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

2. using setTemplate method in your catalog_category_view.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock
    ></body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a layout file catalog_category_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2)Create templte file:

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $block->getData('outputHelper');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()):?>
    <div class="message info empty">
    <div><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= $viewMode ?> products-<?= $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <script> var obj={};</script>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info"
                     id="product-item-info_<?= $_product->getId() ?>"
                     data-container="product-<?= $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = 'left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                            
                                    <script>
                                        id=<?= $id?>;
                                        obj["<?= $id?>"] = 0;
                                    </script>
                                <div class="box-tocart">
                                <div class="field qty">
                                
                                <label class="label" for="<?= $id ?>"><span><?php echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                                <div class="control" data-bind="scope: 'qty_change'">
                                <span class="minus"><button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;"
                                onclick="
                                var result = document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id ?>');
                                var qty = result.value;
                                var custom = [<?php echo $helper->changeQtyStep()[0];?>];
                                var custom1 = <?php echo $helper->changeQtyStep()[1];?>;
                                if (custom1 == 0 || custom1 == '0')
                                {
                                    qty = --qty;
                                    if(qty>=1){
                                    document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    }
                                }else if (custom1 == 1 || custom1 == '1')
                                {
                                    qty = parseInt(qty) - parseInt(custom);
                                    if(qty>=parseInt(custom[0])){
                                    document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                }}
                                else if (custom1 == 2 || custom1 == '2')
                                {
                                    var len=custom.length;
                                    --obj['<?= $id?>'];
                                    var temp=parseInt(qty) - parseInt(custom[obj['<?= $id?>']]);
                                    if(!(temp>=parseInt(custom[0])))
                                    {
                                        document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                        document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = temp;
                                        document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = temp;
                                    }
                                }
                                ">-</button>
                                </span>
                                <input 
                                    type="text"
                                    name="qty"
                                    id="<?= 'qty_'.$id ?>"
                                    value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                    class="input-text qty"
                                    title="<?= __('Qty') ?>"
                                    readOnly/>
                                <span class="plus">
                                <button type="button" style="background-color:#<?= $helper->buttonColor();?>;color:#<?= $helper->signColor();?>;" 
                                onclick="
                                var result = document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id ?>');
                                var qty = result.value;
                                var stock=<?php echo $helper->stockQty( (int)$childIds, $websiteId )?>;
                                var custom = [<?php echo $helper->changeQtyStep()[0];?>];
                                var custom1 = <?php echo $helper->changeQtyStep()[1];?>;
                                
                                if (custom1 == 0 || custom1 == '0')
                                {
                                    qty = ++qty;
                                    if(!(parseInt(qty)>stock)){
                                    document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    }
                                }else if (custom1 == 1 || custom1 == '1')
                                {
                                    qty = parseInt(qty) + parseInt(custom);
                                    if(!(parseInt(qty)>stock)){
                                    document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (custom1 == 2 || custom1 == '2')
                                {
                                    var len=custom.length;
                                    if (obj['<?= $id?>'] < 0 || obj['<?= $id?>'] < '0' )
                                    {
                                        obj['<?= $id?>'] = 1;
                                    }
                                    var temp = parseInt(qty) + parseInt(custom[obj['<?= $id?>']]);
                                    if(!(parseInt(temp)>stock)){
                                    if (obj['<?= $id?>'] == len )
                                    {
                                        document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                        document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = parseInt(qty);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        document.getElementById('<?= 'qty_'.$id?>').value = temp;
                                        document.getElementById('<?= $id.'_qty'?>').value = temp;
                                        ++obj['<?= $id?>'];
                                    }
                                }}
                                ">+</button></span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()):?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <?php $id = $_product->getId(); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= $postParams['data']['product'] ?>"
                                                   >
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   id="<?= $id.'_qty'?>"
                                                   name="qty"
                                                   value="qty"
                                                   >
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="<?= Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                   value="<?=
                                                   $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>"
                                                    >
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                                            <div class="stock available">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ?
                                    $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-primary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')):?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ?
                                    $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-secondary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= $_helper->productAttribute(
                                        $_product,
                                        $_product->getShortDescription(),
                                        'short_description'
                                    ) ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ?
                $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                    $position,
                    'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.product-item-actions'
                ) : '' ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <!-- <script>
            obj['2'] = 10;
            alert(obj['2']);
            console.log(obj);
            </script> -->
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()):?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $escaper->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php endif; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```